# Multiple Primefaces DataTables on one page have the same pagination index

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-5

I have a PrimeFaces 6.2 DataTable with rowExpansions. Each rowExpansion has another DataTable with pagination enabled. The whole construct is within a single form. The backing bean is a ViewScoped ManagedBean.
Selecting a row in a child table will update the parent table. The problem is now that when I change the pagination in a child table and select a row causing an update that the pagination in all other child tables gets the same index. So if for example I am on page while doing the change, all other tables will be on their page 2 as well. The same happens if change the pagination and open or reopen another rowExpansion. So, why on earth do these tables share the same pagination index?
I have already tried to put all child tables in a separate form. This changes nothing.

Comment: Without XHTML this is hard to look at.  But I have had similar issues with datatable in same form and using same `var="row"` had to give each table its own unique 'var`

Comment: @Melloware Unfortunately the number of subtables is dynamic. This makes the naming of var difficult because I think I cannot use EL in there.

Comment: You are correct you can't use EL there  but I think that may be the issue.